# Facing a serialization issue after updating to .net 6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I'm facing the weirdest error after updating to .net 6 (I don't even know if .net 6 have anything to do with that)
I have the following class in which I'm receiving the entities as query params

```
public class GetEntities : IQuery<PagedResponse<EntityResponseModel>>
{
    public Guid EntityId { get; set; }
    public int? Take { get; set; }
    public int? Skip { get; set; }
}
```

So I'm trying to call the endpoint using the following Url:
`https://localhost:5002/api/{entityId}/users?skip=0&take=100`

Which was working fine before, but suddenly started to throw the following error:

> An exception has occured while handling a query.
> System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]. Path: $.skip | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 60.
> ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot get the value of a token type 'String' as a number.

**Note:** When not sending any skip, take values, everything is working fine. But when setting values such as 0 and 100, it's throwing the error.

So anyone have any idea why this error suddenly started to occur? Is it a serialization issue or what?

Comment: when saying after updating, so you just update to a newer version of dotnet 6, mention from which version are you updating? Was the model the same or have you made changes to it, like adding the nullable questions mark?

Comment: Try it with Newtonsoft

Comment: @MaythamFahmi Nope the class have not being changed for the past 130 days, and it was for sure working. So for sure it's when updating from .net 3.1 to .net 6

Comment: @McNets what do you mean? Adding an attribute to the model or what?

Comment: Use Newtonsoft to serialize/deserialize instead of Sytem.Text.Json

Comment: From the error, there is a problem with converting "skip" from string to nullable int. I am not sure how your endpoint looks like, maybe problem is there. Can you add endpoint code?

Comment: A suggestion for debugging, upgrading things does not mean things are consistent as you have this issue. I suggest you change ```int? Take``` to ```string? Take``` and the same for Skip, and check the value of Take and Skip, I am pretty sure contains more than the number and fail to parse it. please try to let me know. if that is the case might need to think differently.

Comment: @MaythamFahmi Making `skip` and `take` `string?` instead of `int?` actually worked. But the received values are pure `0` and `100` nothing more than that

Comment: btw wherein the process, you are using System.Text.Json, can you share that part of the code. the other question, is how can you validate the string of the number are a string without hidden characters? that makes it impossible to parse without cleaning up.

Comment: Can you share your code of web api?